# Possibilities of the dimension of the solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If we have a $n$  linear equations and $m$ unknowns, what are the possibilities for the dimension of the solution space when $n > m$ and when $n < m$ for a homogeneous system of equations? How do I approach this problem? I know it has something to do with the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: what is the dimension of the solution space in terms of the rank and nullity?

Comment: @Callus if you consider the the system of equations as a linear transformation, then the kernel would represent all solutions to the homogenous system of equations, I'm unsure what to do next though

Comment: right, so the dimension of that space is the nullity.  What are the possible ranks if $n>m$ and $n<m$?

Comment: @Callus this is probably wrong, but wouldn't the rank be min(m,n)?

Comment: That's the highest the rank can be.

Comment: So $nullity = columns - rank$, and our columns is $m$: if $m > n$ then $nullity <= m - n$, and if $m < n$ then $nullity <= 0$, but we always have the trivial solution of the zero vector, so the dimension of nullity must be at least 1, right? I must have messed up somewhere.

Comment: rank is between $0$ and $min(m,n)$.  When rank is maximal, nullity is minimal.  your inequalities are going in the wrong direction.

Comment: If $n > m$, isn't it true that $0 \leqslant nullity \leqslant m$ and if $n < m$ we have $m - n \leqslant Nullity \leqslant m$ ?

Comment: yes.  This is getting very long for comments, though, so I'm going to cut it off here.